# SUMIFS: Summing a criteria + 2 numbers on another page given they meet a certain criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am working on a spreadsheet that allows me to sum our business plan price + the changes to the current price of the market based on 2 different chemicals that is on another spreadsheet given they mean a few different conditions. I believe the issue is contained within summing these different items together.

Here is the formula I have tried to use.

```
=SUMIFS(E2+Benzene!M2:M3, Sheet3!A:A,Sheet3!A2,Sheet3!B:B,Sheet3!B2,Sheet3!C:C,Sheet3!C2,Sheet3!D:D,Sheet3!D2)
```

Which tells me that there is a problem with this formula. What would be the best way to go about this?

Thanks for any and all suggestions in advance!

Comment: Some test data and expected output would help here.  Do a minimal set of test data.  With SUMIS the column to be sum should be the same size and shape as the criteria columns.  You are comparing 2 cells to full columns.  They must relate in sequence.  SUMIFS does a row to row comparison.  I think you are using the wrong formula but do not have enough information to help determine what is the correct formula.

Comment: Here is an article about Sumifs function, you may have a look. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the formula you provided is that the first argument of the `SUMIFS` function should be the range of cells to sum, but you have entered `E2+Benzene!M2:M3` which is not a valid range. Instead, you should enter the range of cells that you want to sum as the first argument.

For example, if you want to sum the values in column E of Sheet3 based on multiple criteria, your formula should look like this:

`=SUMIFS(Sheet3!E:E, Sheet3!A:A,Sheet3!A2,Sheet3!B:B,Sheet3!B2,Sheet3!C:C,Sheet3!C2,Sheet3!D:D,Sheet3!D2)`

This formula will sum the values in column E of Sheet3 where the corresponding values in columns A, B, C and D meet the criteria specified in cells A2, B2, C2 and D2 respectively.

If you want to add the value from another sheet (e.g. Benzene) to this sum based on certain conditions, you can use another SUMIFS function and add its result to the first one.